# Button not responding to onclick in chrome/ safari, but works on code snippet on stack overflow, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small function, displayMessage, that when the button is clicked, a div box should appear.

I've tried this on both chrome and safari and the box will not appear unless I put parenthesis after displayMessage, which should not be necessary.

However, the pop up box appears in this, stack overflow's code snippet.

What is going on in chrome and why is the code functioning on this site???

Also, this is what appears in the console on developer tools for chrome: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at script.js:4

where btn.onclick = displayMessage; is script.js:4

```js
//js

var btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.onclick = displayMessage;

function displayMessage() {
  var html = document.querySelector('html');

  var panel = document.createElement('div');
  panel.setAttribute('class', 'msgBox');
  html.appendChild(panel);

  var msg = document.createElement('p');
  msg.textContent = 'This is a message box';
  panel.appendChild(msg);

  var closeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  closeBtn.textContent = 'x';
  panel.appendChild(closeBtn);

  closeBtn.onclick = function() {
    panel.parentNode.removeChild(panel);
  }
}
```

```css
.msgBox {
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
       width: 200px;
       background: #eee;
     }
     .msgBox p {
       line-height: 1.5;
       padding: 10px 20px;
       color: #333;
     }
     .msgBox button {
       background: none;
       border: none;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       font-size: 1.1rem;
       color: #aaa;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Custom Message Box</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button>Display message box</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use selector as body instead of html

Comment: This is because the snippet editor wraps your code in a document load method. You need to do this yourself normally. `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myFunction);` You should call you code in the myFunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<script>` tag should be bottom of `body` container or we need to listen `DOMContentLoaded` event before `querying the DOM`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Custom Message Box</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <button>Display message box</button>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

or

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      var btn = document.querySelector('button');
      btn.onclick = displayMessage;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the listener, looking for DOM Ready event.

```js
//js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  var btn = document.querySelector('button');
  btn.onclick = displayMessage;
});

function displayMessage() {
  var html = document.querySelector('html');

  var panel = document.createElement('div');
  panel.setAttribute('class', 'msgBox');
  html.appendChild(panel);

  var msg = document.createElement('p');
  msg.textContent = 'This is a message box';
  panel.appendChild(msg);

  var closeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  closeBtn.textContent = 'x';
  panel.appendChild(closeBtn);

  closeBtn.onclick = function() {
    panel.parentNode.removeChild(panel);
  }
}
```

```css
.msgBox {
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
       width: 200px;
       background: #eee;
     }
     .msgBox p {
       line-height: 1.5;
       padding: 10px 20px;
       color: #333;
     }
     .msgBox button {
       background: none;
       border: none;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       font-size: 1.1rem;
       color: #aaa;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Custom Message Box</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button>Display message box</button>
</body>
</html>
```